# Изменить флаг оплаты по условию, если сумма меньше или равно 0

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте, 
подскажите функцию которой можно изменить флаг оплаты на "оплачено". 
Пытаюсь сделать следующее, 
если сумма заказа равна или меньше 0, то заказ "ОПЛАЧЕН".

в файле bitrix/php_interface/s1/init.php 
пишу

```
<?php 
   AddEventHandler('sale',"OnOrderUpdate" , 'PayedIfNoEMoney');
     function PayedIfNoEMoney( $orderId , $arFields='' , $arOrder='' ) {
       if($arFields["PRICE"] <= 0){
          CSaleOrder::StatusOrder($orderId, 'Y');
          CSaleOrder::PayOrder($ID, "Y");   
       }
    }
?>
```

но меняется только статус оплаты, а флаг остается "не оплачено"

подскажите как изменить флаг оплаты? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не объявленная переменная `$ID` исправьте строку:

```
   CSaleOrder::PayOrder($orderId, "Y");
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! несколько дней мучился над этим!

Comment: @SerhiyBilik советую использовать ide (например phpstorm). Помогает избегать подобных ошибок.

Comment: Я прислушаюсь к вашим советам!
сейчас использую netbeans